# unwanted lines in table when collapsing tr in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, doctype

I have a table with expand/collapse javascript acting on the class value assigned to tr.
See below html code.
This all works fine in Chrome, but in IE when I expand and then collapse the www row, I get additional unwanted lines in the xxx and zzz rows. The lines look like they are borders (see css td border-style definition). It looks as if the borders of the collapsed and hidden rows are still shown (non-button rows are a little less high than the button rows, apparently because of standard button padding and border widths).

[image: screenprint from IE]

Why is this, and how can I prevent this from occurring?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Example</title>
      <style type="text/css">
body, p {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-style: normal;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 4.5pt;
    margin-top: 0pt;
}

table {
    border: solid black 1pt;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 153);
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1pt;
    padding: 0cm 5pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 10pt;
    font-style: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
}
td {
    border-style: dotted dotted none none;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1pt;
    padding: 0cm 5pt;
    color: black;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 10pt;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 4.5pt;
    margin-top: 0pt;
}

input.buttonSeq {
    color: blue;
    background: ffffcc;
    border: none;
    margin-left:0pt;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
}

</style>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//expand and collapse tr functions based on class
function ToggleTRbyClass(clss){
    var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i=0; i!=trs.length; i++) {
        if (trs[i].className == clss) {
            if (    trs[i].style.display == "none")
                {
                trs[i].style.display = "table-row"
                }
            else    {
                trs[i].style.display = "none"
                }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
      </head>
   <body>
      <br><br>
      <table style="table-layout:fixed word-break:break-all">
         <col width="120">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Element</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr bgcolor="ffffcc">
               <td align="left" style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold">
                  <div><input type="button" class="buttonSeq" onclick="ToggleTRbyClass('www'); return true;" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='hand'" value="www"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none" class="www">
               <td>element1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none" class="www">
               <td>element2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none" class="www">
               <td>element3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="ffffcc">
               <td align="left" style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold">
                  <div><input type="button" class="buttonSeq" onclick="ToggleTRbyClass('xxx'); return true;" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='hand'" value="xxx"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none" class="xxx">
               <td>element4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="ffffcc">
               <td align="left" style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold">
                  <div><input type="button" class="buttonSeq" onclick="ToggleTRbyClass('zzz'); return true;" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='hand'" value="zzz"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none" class="zzz">
               <td>element5</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table><br></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXBJE/) for you. I'm not seeing anything odd in IE9 on Win7.

Comment: Funnily enough IE6 works fine, too. With display:block though, since it's not a fan of table-row. Which IE version are you using? Compat or "Standards" mode?

Comment: I use IE 9.0.8112.16421 Update versions 9.0.4 (took that from the IE about screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a [doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration) as the first line in your markup. Without a `doctype`, IE will render in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which is essentially the IE 5.5 rendering engine. Quirks mode greatly effects the box model and Javascript support, among other things.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Specifying the `doctype` will make your example work as it does in Firefox.

**Edit:**

The grey background comes from the following rule, which is technically wrong (you need to specify the `#` symbol when using hex colors:

```
input.buttonSeq {
    color: blue;
    background: ffffcc; /* change this to #ffffcc */
    border: none;
    margin-left:0pt;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Interesting - that solves the odd behavior all right. It does change the button format though (light bluee background introduced) so will have to do additonal stuff there. Not quite understand this though - what is quirks mode exactly? I will try your link to that subject and catch up on my knowledge here!

Comment: See edit. The reason why there is a grey background is because there's a malformed CSS rule (which apparently gets applied in standards mode, and not in quirks mode).

Comment: Again - very interesting. Goes to show that something may seem to be working correctly all the time and still have bugs in it - thx!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting the display to `"table-row"`, set it to `""` so that the default behaviour comes back. Older versions of IE don't support `table-row` and need `block` instead.

If your CSS overrides the default (ie. if you used it to hide a class of rows from the start), try:

```
try {tr.style.display = "table-row";}
catch(e) {tr.style.display = "block";}
```

And add a DOCTYPE, like wsanville said.